# Dynamically change variables in WLST script

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

I'm creating a bunch of `.py` WLST scripts (15-20) which will each check a different setting in a `Weblogic` environment. For example, password requirements, security settings, user properties etc.

However, I want to run these scripts in a number of `WebLogic` environments, all having different host URLs and credentials. Is there an easy way to dynamically change the connection details for each script as they are run in different environments:

script:

```
connect(x,y,z)
```

script in env 1:

```
connect('weblogic','welcome1','example-host1:7001')
```

script in env 2:

```
connect('weblogic','welcome2','example-host1:7001')
```

This is my first occasion asking a question on stackoverflow after using it as a source for the first couple of years of my career, so apologies if this issue is described poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer would be . Keep Environment related properties in the  property file . And read those properties using Python (Jython)

```
from java.io import FileInputStream

propInputStream = FileInputStream("preprodenv.properties") 
configProps = Properties()
configProps.load(propInputStream)

adminHost=configProps.get("admin.host)
adminPort=configProps.get("admin.port")
adminUserName=configProps.get("admin.userName")
adminPassword=configProps.get("admin.password")

# t3 or t3s depends upon your config
adminURL = "t3://"+adminHost+":"+adminPort
connect(adminUserName, adminPassword, adminURL)
```

## Option#2

Keep the environment related information in properties and read using

```
loadProperties('c:/temp/myLoad.properties')
```

or pass it as argument to your wlst script `-loadProperties='C:\temp\myLoad.properties'`

Anything would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the hostnames will be different in different environments. The way we do this is by creating an "env shell script" which contains a mapping using simple case statements. We then create a wrapper script that iterates over various environments in the "env shell script". Does this help or do you need more details ?

Comment: More detail would be helpful if you can provide!

Comment: An example would be even better.